# What is a good way to implement Reservation database EJB 3.0

Tags: java, database, arrays, database-design, ejb

In the system I am working on, we allow customers to make reservations for a lot of things. Currently, I have these 2 entities:

```
@Entity
public class Reservation implements Serializable {
    ...
    private long startTime;
    private long endTime;
    private int  status;
    @ManyToOne
    private Customer theCustomer;   // record who made this reservation
    @ManyToOne
    private ReservableUnit theUnit; // record what this reservation is for
    ...
}

@Entity
public class ReservableUnit implements Serializable {

    private int numOfAvailableUnits;
    ...
    private int[][][] firstMonth = new int[31][24][2];
    ...
    private int[][][] fourthMonth = new int[31][24][2];
}

//status
public static final int AVAILABLE = 0;
public static final int BLOCKED   = 1;
public static final int RESERVED  = 2;
```

In the ReservableUnit table, I have 4 int[31][24][2] arrays to store the status of all 30-minute time slots up to 3 months ahead. I used arrays because I think that when I bring them into memory, it would be fast to check if the requested time slots are available or not.

A friend of mine told me that this is not a good approach because I have to store big objects in the database. He suggested that I should remove those fields and when I need to check if the slots are available, I should count the number of reservations that have been made for those slots by counting rows in the Reservation table. Obviously, my friend's way can save us some space in the database. However, in the long run, we will have a lot of rows in the Reservation table which means it will take longer and longer to process the status of slots.

I am a student with no solid working experience on designing database. Hence, I'd be very grateful if someone could give me an advice on this matter.

Best regards,

James Tran

Comment: A database is not just a place where you store data. It's a place where data is stored in order to be queries. Always ask yourself if you could do a any kind of query with your design. For example, could you easily query all the reservations made for a given item in the slot going from 9:00 to 9:30, in september. If it's not doable (and it's not, with your design), then you have a problem. Serialized objects in a database are generally a very bad idea. They're absolutely not queryable, are impossible to read/change manually, and ae hard to handle when their class changes.

Comment: You're right that I cannot make direct queries to the object in the database. However, I want to emphasize that these arrays are just additional fields I put in to help the server process reservations quickly. Without them, I still can count rows in the Reservation table to get the result. Nevertheless, as the Reservation table keep growing, I wonder if counting be less and less efficient comparing to pulling the array out of the database into the memory to process. If you don't like my way and my friend's way, could you please suggest another way for me =)?

Comment: I didn't say I ddn't like your friends way. Just keep data normalized, put indexes where needed in the database, and everything should be fine. Databases are exceptionally fast when well-configured, even if they contain millions of rows.

Comment: Thks for your comment :D. I will delete those unnecessary fields then.